# Css Media Queries Resolution Issue

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I can use CSS Media Queries to detect screen resolution and make a different page load if the screen resolution is under 1024x768? I also need to know if I can place this query in my master.css script? or where it would need to be placed?

Sitemap (without Java included)

- *Index.html*      (Main Page)
- *About.html*      (About Page)
- *Missing.html*    (404)
- *Small.html*      (the smaller version I am trying to get to load)
- *ie8.css*         (conditional css for internet explorer 8)
- *Master.css* (Main Stylesheet)

Comment: Put it where you need it.  There is nothing more to it.

Comment: I need someone to actually type out the query and elaborate further on what I need to do! :(

Comment: suggest to put it in files that all pages require / load it .

Answer (score 1):

You can serve up different styles to a page based on the width of the browser viewport in various ways, such as this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  your styles here
}
```

You can put that anywhere in your style sheets.

Be aware, though, that you can't use media queries like this to *load a different page*. For that, you'd need some kind of device detection script.

Comment: Can I have it overrun the current page with the text "This is a graphic design portfolio; your screen resolution is too small to view this webpage in it's entirety. Please try reviewing it on any screen resolution of 1024x768 or larger!"???? Make the stylesheet manually overrun all of the html of the index.html page?

Comment: Well, you _could_ ... but I'd say that would be rather silly, TBH. If I saw a graphic designer giving out that message, I'd run away, as it's against all principles of the web. You are better off accepting the fluid nature of the web, and letting your design and layout adapt to different devices. There's no reason someone should't be able to view your portfolio on a small screen.

Comment: You have a valid point, The reason that I want this is because my artwork is pixel based and is large it doesn't scale well either because it is not "vectorized", I designed the webpage to display on monitors vs. tablet, phones, etc. as you would have to scroll on these devices to view the pieces, which takes away from the experience.

Comment: I have heard of graceful degradation but as this is pixel based and the images won't scale it really isn't suited to mobile platforms, However any new websites I do will be in %'s and not pixels. For lack of a better word I feel anything under 1024x768 is past my "graceful degradation" of the website. I was asking though more or less how to implement the popup as I am a little lost on this aspect!

Comment: Images can scale to any dimensions, so that's not a problem, and you can tell the small-screen device to fit the layout within its viewport if you don't want to bother with a responsive design. Even if everything is really small, it will give users some idea of your work, and may prompt them to view the site on a larger screen if they want a better look. Denying them anything will most likely make them grumpy and turn them away. Let the user decide the experience.

Comment: Vectors scale well because they are "line based memory" whereas Pixel will distort, I will go about making a mobile ready version in the future. I heard that CSS media queries were the way to go! I have some JS to detect resolution and display a new page if under 1024x768, the problem is that when it is implemented even the pages at 1024x768 display the smaller html! If you could tell me what is wrong with my code I would greatly appreciate it! http://pastebin.com/XNDHxVPj

Comment: Perhaps ask a new question for that. I can't advise on the JS, but interesting issue.